# MacBook pro stops charging when the laptop closed

Tags: macbook-pro, charging

I'm using MacBook Pro 13 inch 2019 version with USB-C cable.
The problem is that while charging, it stops when I close the lid.

Does anyone know why this happens? and How to solve this?

Comment: How are you determining it's not charging?

Comment: Because the indicator of the battery right above the window shows 'Not charging' and 'Battery source: Power Adopter'

Comment: If it’s closed, how do you see it?  Are you operating in closed clamshell mode?

Comment: Ah, I understand what you mean. I'm assuming that it stops charging when I close it. I'm assuming that because the battery indicator never increases and only decreases and when I reopen, it shows  'Not charging' and 'Battery source: Power Adopter'.